# Get Filesize when using Matrix flle field

Tags: matrix

How do you get the filesize of the file when using Matrix?

```
{downloads}
  {download_name} {file_size} {size}
{/download}
```

returns

```
Download name {file_size} {size}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the particular file as a tag pair around file_size. Something like this:

```
{downloads}
  {download_name} {download_file}{file_size}{/download_file}
{/downloads}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried the above and it does return the filesize but it also returns the file name as well `http://path/to/file53289`

Comment: Simply remove {download_file} from Laura's answer.

Comment: When I remove {download_file} the {file_size} will return {file_size}

Comment: I have to said I'm getting different results with my original code. Can you provide your code for us to look at?

Comment: I guess @LauraMontgomery wanted you to remove the `{download_name}`.